# ruby-idiomatic hashes vs arrays

Tags: data-structures, ruby, array

So I am still fairly new to ruby, though I have noticed that it is very hard to create 2d-array and that hashes seem to be more of the go to data structure than arrays.

I was wondering why the Ruby community is so focused on Hashes and maybe if there is something more ruby-idiomatic than a 2d-array when trying to create something like a game board.

Comment: You may find the SO question [How to create a 2D array of objects in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357284/how-to-create-a-2d-array-of-objects-in-ruby) useful.

Comment: @MichaelT that would answer the so question very effectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times a hash can be more convenient than an array.  The use of a compound key (or hash of hashes) can be used to simulate multidimensional arrays.  This is of signficant use when the array would otherwise be a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) or a [jagged array].  Hashes can be easier for these cases, and they can be surprisingly common.

However, hashes aren't ordered data.  While it is very easy to put the data into a hash, it becomes more complicated to get it back out in an ordered way.  Much more complicated than just using the appropriate array in the first place.

Another factor to consider, hashes are indeed easy.  There are a number of transformations with ruby arrays that can be confusing - there are nearly twice as many methods in Array as in Hash.  Thus, if you're just tossing some data that you will want to access (and don't care about the order), especially if it is data that isn't related to each other, putting it in a hash is much easier conceptually.

Many times, hashes will stand in for a quick anonymous data object with some fields rather than making up an entirely new class for it (this is likely a better choice than metaprogramming an anonymous object with the fields to pass around).  It is easier to remember that 'userid' is in the 'userid' key rather than element 0 of the array.

Using a hash is only idiomatic when the data doesn't have an underlying, enumerable order to it already.

Comment: Hashes are ordered data in Ruby 1.9 and greater.  Though the order may not be what is expected, it is ordered.  Ruby 1.8 hashes are not guaranteed to be in any order at all.

Comment: @vgoff yes, they are in insertion order (akin to the LinkedHashMap in Java), though that is a linked list backing that order and it doesn't help significantly when you want to get the cell to the left, right, up, down of the current one.  That is just the enumeration order of the hash, it doesn't mean it is a good choice for storing the squares of a chessboard. It becomes difficult to iterate the display over rows and columns - which is what arrays are good for.

Comment: So doesn't that invalidate what you state about "hashes aren't ordered data".  I didn't state in any way that it was a good choice for anything, I left judgement out totally. I only mentioned the objective fact that they are indeed ordered, and predictably so.

Comment: So using a hash within a hash is not uncommon to replicate a 2d-array?

Comment: @TallPaul I would more expect to see a hash where the keys are things like `"4,3"` or `"6,2"` to indicate the 2d array position of `[4][3]` or `[6][2]`.  I would not expect to see a hash of `{4}{3}` to indicate a board position of 4,3.

Comment: @MichaelT That makes more sense to me than what I thought, my only question now is how would you iterate over it. I know you could do hashname.each do |X|, but what if you only wanted to iterate over one row, such as [4,x]. I feel like that could become very sloppy code

Comment: @TallPaul see, thats where arrays are better than hashes - you have ordered data.  You would still need to set up the two loops to iterate over it. If you are very careful with the hash, and insert in order, you can get it out in order... but if you ever delete or insert out of order, you've lost that.  For a grid game board, using a 2d array is a better solution.

Comment: @MichaelT ok sounds good. In Java and Python I always used a 2d array, but it seemed that the Ruby community tried to stay as far away from using arrays as possible